# PHP: shell_exec is neither Defined nor disabled

Tags: php, linux, shell

Well, I know there are already lots of related questions but non of them address my issue.
In my case, I want to use the shell_exec function but, I see that the `shell_exec` function is not defined and not even mentioned in the `disable_functions` list in php.ini.

here is the php.ini snippet

```
; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names.
; http://php.net/disable-functions
disable_functions =

; This directive allows you to disable certain classes for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of class names.
; http://php.net/disable-classes
disable_classes =
```

and here is how I'm using the function

```
if(!function_exists('shell_exec')) {
    die("shell_exec is not found");
}
```

**NOTE**: I'm using Linux version `CentOS release 6.9 (Final)` and `php -v` outputs as follow

```
ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 7.0.28 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 09:27:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.28, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was using PHP-FPM that added the following line to the configuration of each domain at `/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php-fpm.d/`

```
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
```

So, this is what I did to make the shell_exec function available to use

```
mkdir /var/cpanel/ApachePHPFPM
echo "php_admin_value_disable_functions : exec,passthru,system">/var/cpanel/ApachePHPFPM/system_pool_defaults.yaml
/scripts/php_fpm_config --rebuild
```

and at the end restarted the PHP-FPM from WHM, and that's it.